# Get the "Error number" of a "warning". "Microsoft Office Access can't append all the records in the append query"

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

I want to identify the error number of this "append query" error so that I can display a message using the ErrorHandler", to the user to use a different method. Example use the "Edit Form" instead of the "New Entry Form".

[image]

I tried the following:

```
ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Oops!  An error occurred:" & vbCrLf & _
          "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
```

But I continue to get a Error 0: dialogue response

[image]

What I need to do is determine what error occurred to provide instructions on what to do next to the user.
then I can use the following:

```
If Err.Number = xxxx Then
            MsgBox Me.CoNmtxt & "/" & Me.FrnNmtxt & "/" & Me.DptNmtxt & vbCrLf & "have been entered already" &  vbCrLf & "Please use the [Directors Edit form] to enter or edit the" & vbCrLf & "Directors Name and Email", vbInformation, "! ! ! New Director Entry Error ! ! !"
End If
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure there is an error number to be retrieved. Note there also no error description returned. This is a failure of SQL action. Should see the same message if you try manual append with a query object as opposed to VBA execution.

Comment: Instead of trying to capture the error, find out why it errors and prevent it. With such limited information in your question, I would guess that appending records is causing some sort of key violation.

Comment: @braX is right; what you see _is_ the error message, and it is perfectly clear. So, debug the record data you try to append to resolve the key violation.

Comment: Something very wrong with business process and code that allows a user to even try to input invalid data. Why is append action needed? Are you not using a bound form for New Entry?

Comment: Also note there are no End or Debug buttons on that popup. It is a Warning, not a VBA run-time Error Message. SQL warnings can be disabled via code, I think including this one.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. I will use a different method to prevent the users from re-entering existing record key index combinations.